# Getting panic for running goroutines even with mutex locking and defer

Tags: go, mutex, goroutine

```
**func (p *linkedList) showalldoctorsrecursive() error {
    defer wg.Done()
    mutex.Lock()
    {
        if p.head != nil {
            printRecursiveF(p.head)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("The list is empty.")
        }
    }
    mutex.Unlock()
    return nil
}
func (p *linkedList) showalldoctorsfront() error {
    defer wg.Done()
    mutex.Lock()
    {
        if p.head != nil {
            printfront(p.head)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("The list is empty.")
        }
    }
    mutex.Unlock()
    return nil
}
func printRecursiveF(n *Node2) {
    if n != nil {
        printRecursiveF(n.next)
        fmt.Println(n.item, n.next.time)
    }
}
func printfront(n *Node2) {
    if n != nil {
        fmt.Println(n.item)
        fmt.Println(n.item, n.next.time)
    }
}**

func (p *queue) displayallpatients() error {
    defer wg.Done()
    mutex.Lock()
    {
        currentNode := p.front
        if currentNode == nil {
            fmt.Println("There are no patients.")
            return nil
        }
        fmt.Println("Displaying all patients and their appointment times")
        fmt.Println(currentNode.item, currentNode.time)
        for currentNode.next != nil {
            currentNode = currentNode.next
            fmt.Println(currentNode.item, currentNode.time)
        }
    }
    mutex.Unlock()
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var num, num1, num2 int
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)
    wg.Add(3)
    myList := &linkedList{nil, 0}
    myQueue := &queue{nil, nil, 0}
    for {
        fmt.Println("Please enter 1 to check for patient or 2 to check for doctor.Alternatively,enter 3 to exit menu")
        fmt.Scanln(&num)
        _, err := mainmenu(num)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else if num == 3 {
            break
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Please proceed to the main menu >")
        }

        if num == 1 {
            fmt.Println("Patient Main Menu")
            fmt.Println("1. Add Patient")
            fmt.Println("2. Remove Last Patient")
            fmt.Println("3. Update Patient Details")
            fmt.Println("4. Display All Patients")
            fmt.Println("--------------")
            fmt.Println("Please enter a number to access the menu")
            fmt.Scanln(&num1)
            _, err2 := patientmenu(num1)
            if err2 != nil {
                fmt.Println(err2)
            } else if num1 == 1 {
                myQueue.addPatient()
            } else if num1 == 2 {
                myQueue.removelastpatient()
            } else if num1 == 3 {
                myQueue.updatepatient()
            } else if num1 == 4 {
                go myQueue.displayallpatients()
            }
    }

        } else if num == 2 {
            fmt.Println("Doctor Main Menu")
            fmt.Println("1. Add Doctor")
            fmt.Println("2. Search For Doctor Thru Name")
            fmt.Println("3. Search For Doctors Thru Available Time")
            fmt.Println("4. Update Doctor Details")
            fmt.Println("5. Display All Doctors(Recursive)")
            fmt.Println("6. Display All Doctors")
            fmt.Println("--------------")
            fmt.Println("Please enter a number to access the menu")
            fmt.Scanln(&num2)
            _, err3 := doctormenu(num2)
            if err3 != nil {
                fmt.Println(err3)
            } else if num2 == 1 {
                myList.addDoctors()
            } else if num2 == 2 {
                myList.searchdoctor()
            } else if num2 == 3 {
                myList.searchdoctortiming()
            } else if num2 == 4 {
                myList.updatedoctor()
            } else if num2 == 5 {
                go myList.showalldoctorsrecursive()
            } else if num2 == 6 {
                go myList.showalldoctorsfront()
            }
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0x89ec50)
        c:/go/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x49
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x89ec48)
        c:/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x6b
main.main()
        C:/Projects/Go/src/xxx/main.go:145 +0xd85
exit status 2
```

I try to run goroutines and apply mutex locking and defer. However, I will face panic when running the goroutines. Is there a way I can solve this? I created a queue and linked list with some functions to display, enqueue(add) and dequeue(pop) and apply some concurrency to this. I know that `wg.Add(n)` and the n is the number of goroutines you run and you want to use mutex locking to ensure that the goroutines will run one at a time.

Comment: can you share the complete code and also the input sequence that gives you deadlock? From the cursory look at the code, you are adding 3 to the wait group. so if 3 goroutines don't perform wg.Done() then you will get deadlock error.

Comment: @SaiRaviTejaK I just added at the top.

Answer (score 2):

There is no mutex.Unlock() when the code executes:

```
if currentNode == nil {
    fmt.Println("There are no patients.")
    return nil
}
```

You are locking and never unlock:

```
func (p *queue) displayallpatients() error {
    defer wg.Done()
    mutex.Lock() // <- here we acquire a lock
    {
        currentNode := p.front
        if currentNode == nil {
            fmt.Println("There are no patients.")
            return nil // <- here we return without releasing the lock
        }
        // ...
    }
    mutex.Unlock() // <- never reach if currentNode == nil is true
    return nil
}
```

You can solve this either using defer or don't do early return:

```
func (p *queue) displayallpatients() error {
    defer wg.Done()
    defer mutex.Unlock() // <- defers the execution until the func returns (will release the lock)
    mutex.Lock()
    {
        currentNode := p.front
        if currentNode == nil {
            fmt.Println("There are no patients.")
            return nil
        }
        // ...
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

You can find more details in the [docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements)

Comment: So i need to add mutex unlock below the code u mentioned even when I put mutex.unlock() on fmt.Println("Displaying all patients and their appointment times") ?

``` 
fmt.Println(currentNode.item, currentNode.time) for currentNode.next != nil { currentNode = currentNode.next fmt.Println(currentNode.item, currentNode.time) } } mutex.Unlock() 
```
@xodmqjw

Comment: @Smbsg, when you do early return (when currentNode == nil is true), you never reach the piece of code when you unlock the mutex, because execution of the function is stopped. So after locking you got a deadlock. You can either unlock with defer (as I wrote, add it before the 'if' branch), or don't do early return.

Comment: So if there is just only one return I can just mutex lock and mutex unlock just before the return? Anyway thanks for the great response.

Comment: Yes, you can do it as you do it in function showalldoctorsrecursive(), for instance.

Comment: ```
func (p *linkedList) showalldoctorsrecursive() error {
 defer wg.Done()
 mutex.Lock()

 {
  if p.head != nil {
   printRecursiveF(p.head)
  } else {
   fmt.Println("The list is empty.")
  }
 }
 mutex.Unlock()
 return nil
}
func printRecursiveF(n *Node2) {
 mutex.Lock()
 {
  if n != nil {
   printRecursiveF(n.next)
   fmt.Println(n.item, n.next.time)
  }
 }
 mutex.Unlock()
}
```
I am getting deadlock for this though. Is it because of the missing defer wg_done?

Comment: @Smbsg Why are you locking again in printRecursiveF function? Because you already locked in the showalldoctorsrecursive function so you don't have to lock in printRecursiveF.

Comment: In first line of printRecursiveF you acquired a lock. Then you make recursive call (from printRecursiveF call printRecursiveF) and printRecursiveF is trying to acquire the lock again. But you've already locked and did not release the lock yet. And here you get deadlock. You should lock before calling printRecursiveF to avoid locking in recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wg.Add(1)` before starting a go routine.